# Is `UDIF read/write image` bootable on non-Apple hardware?

Tags: system-installation, flash-memory, apple, disk-image

Some guides on the internet suggest that it is possible to convert ISO disc image files (`.iso`) into an non-.iso image format (`.img` or `.dmg`) with `hdiutil` on OS X.

However, the manual page for `hdiutil` says that it basically only supports conversion into several `UDIF` formats.

Are images in the `UDIF` format bootable on non-Apple hardware?  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) claims that UDIF, Universal Disc Image Format, is an Apple proprietary format, giving you the impression that it's not compatible with third-party hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is!

Source: I just performed the instructions from the [link referenced](http://blog.tinned-software.net/create-bootable-usb-stick-from-iso-in-mac-os-x/) in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114987) to a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114984/how-to-create-a-bootable-linux-installation-usb-from-an-iso-in-os-x) on my late 2013 MBP using the debian 7.7.0 amd64 DVD iso. Then I took the stick out, stuck it in my Windows gaming rig (no apple hardware what-so-ever), and it booted fine (and fast!).

Comment: The problem here is that, when I converted my UDF ISO to `UDRW - UDIF read/write image` then copied it (`dd` style) to my USB, it still wasn't bootable.  In fact, the file was exactly the same as the input ISO file, to the bit.  I wonder if its possible that the debian ISO was in some kind of "isohybrid" format, and that this conversion is "not enough" for other UDF ISO files : http://superuser.com/q/1063220/39364